My Laptop can't connect to some websites (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, 403 error)
I'm have this problem on my laptop where it can't seem to connect with some websites.
When I try to access the websites I get these erorr
Screenshot of the errors https://imgur.com/a/2dbZ7NE
For psychologytoday.com, If I click the website from Google search it says forbidden. If I type it in I’m fine.
I have tried restarting my network and reconnecting and I still get the same issue. I've also tried edge and still the same.
Here are the list of websites
https://homeguide.com
https://psychologytoday.com
https://binance.com
https://randomness.app
https://microsoft.com
https://5sensesgift.com
EDIT:
Thanks, it's been solved. Seems some of these sites have restricted access for certain geographic locations and the router issues too

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are many potential sources for this kind of error:
DNS server not working properly, DNS client not working properly, Incorrect DNS settings, Incorrect Chrome settings (especially experimental features), Outdated entries in the operating system’s DNS cache,  VPN or antivirus software or a firewall preventing connection

a few things to check: 1. are you always using HTTPS? some of the errors you showed pictures of could be HTTPS related (in that its missing) but since we can;t see the URL we can;t tell. second, when you search on google, do you scroll down past the ads and sponsored results before clicking on the result you want? do you have a pihole server or other adblocking service?

You state, "If I click the website from Google search it says forbidden. If I type it in I’m fine."
The logical reason for that is a Google Search does not have the actual endpoint, e.g. https://www.psychologytoday.com/us (if you are trying to connect from an ISP inside the U.S.A.) or https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl (if the server is elsewhere, e.g., from a VPN), but rather through a redirect, a URL different from that displayed in the search.
Those redirects can be eliminated in various ways.

Visiting Google's search engine via https://www.google.com/ncr should avoid a country-specific redirect.
There might be browser settings to avoid redirect. For example, in Firefox, set privacy.query_stripping.redirect to true.
There are third-party add-ons, such as Google search link fix and ClearURLs, that strip redirects.


I had to come back to this again after experiencing the same problem. Thank you
